# Find the planes of symmetry between two intersecting planes

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

Okay, so I have two planes which intersect at a right angle. I have their normal vectors (which have different lengths). They intersect and form a line. I now need to find the equations of these two planes which are at an angle of 45deg between the two other planes.

[image: this is the information I have]

I tried normalizing the vectors, but that gives me ugly values. Any other way around?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please use MathJax to render math correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have normal vectors with equal lenghts, then the angle you are looking for is the sum of those two vectors. (Diagonal of a rhombus in general)                   Your normal vectors don't have equal lenght, so normalize them (divide by the corresponding lenght) and then add. You started correctly.

Comment: thank you! I did it that way and it's all good now. I just dislike seeing square roots.

Comment: @Tjey Get used to it.